# Getting "ruby-2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/forwardable.rb:157 forwarding to private method" while running rspec

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-2.4, ruby-upgrade

I have upgraded my application from Ruby 2.2.3 to Ruby 2.4.2, Rails version is 5.1.4. I am able to upgrade the application but when I run 'bundle exec rspec' getting too many lines similar to

```
..... "ruby-2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/forwardable.rb:157 forwarding to private method" ...
```

I came across the link which explains the reason for these lines:
 [Forwardable breaks on private methods in ruby 2.4](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12782)
but I didn't get any solution to remove them.

Can anyone guide me how can I remove these lines ?